# how to limit website content visibility by group odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have content on the website that is part of a subscription. based on the subscription I will add the user to a group how to show content based on the group in the home page

also to hide some part of the page is the user (is login)

my code of

```
  <template id="custom_header" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Header">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="id">my_header</attribute>
      <attribute name="group">base.group_public</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </template>
```

Comment: to show element according to group, just add groups="module.group_name" inside the xml tag, something like this : <th groups="product.group_uom">UoM</th>

Comment: To check if user is logged, use this native method "user_id._is_public()", it returs True if the user is not logged

Comment: mabrok, let me know if it works and I will post it as solution

Comment: @m0r7y sorry for the late reply I tried it but it did not work I used
`groups="base.group_public"` to show the nav bar for public users only and show a different one for loged in user
but did not know how to user `"user_id._is_public()"`

Comment: You can look at this addons/portal/views/portal_templates.xml to see how the user_id._is_public() works

Comment: @m0r7y I added the code for my `group` tried you `groups="product.group_uom"` and it works but not `groups="base.group_public"`

Comment: I think you can replace base.group_public by the is_public() method,

Comment: can `"user_id._is_public()"` be used to hide the nav items when if the user is logged in

Comment: Off course, that is the point of the method

Comment: @m0r7y <attribute name="t-if">user_id._is_public()</attribute> it works thank you can it be used with a group names as will `t-if="not user_id.product.group_uom"` some thing like this

Comment: @m0r7y This a hacky way to get around this this question  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604027/how-to-create-a-custom-template-for-the-website-navigation-odoo-13` which I added a bounty on an no one want to answer it
thanks a lot this is a life saver

Comment: could you confirm my answer, thank you.

Comment: I answer for both post. You can confirm two or the one post and set this one to duplicate. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this one that you can find in addons/portal/views/portal_templates.xml.

```
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top_menu_collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto text-right" id="top_menu">
                        <li class="nav-item divider" t-ignore="true" t-if="not user_id._is_public()"/>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown" t-ignore="true" t-if="not user_id._is_public()">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <b>
                                    <span t-esc="user_id.name[:23] + '...' if user_id.name and len(user_id.name) &gt; 25 else user_id.name"/>
                                </b>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu js_usermenu" role="menu">
                                <a id="o_logout" class="dropdown-item" t-attf-href="/web/session/logout?redirect=/" role="menuitem">Logout</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

the method **_is_public()** return True if the "user" is not logged else false

Comment: I works like if statement so can I use it like this `t-if="not user_id.product.group_uom"`

Comment: @MoazMabrok, If you want to play with group, you have to do something like this : t-if="request.env.user.has_group('product.group_uom')"

Comment: using this implies that the user is connected

Comment: so it means that 
1> there is a user 
2> that user is in `product.group_uom`

Comment: I will confirm both, although they can be solved by this method they are different questions and as I said it is a hacky method for the other question so if no one answer fo the other I will confirm yours 

can you explain in the other question that it is a work around thank for your help